# Webform content creator - populate entity bundle field with a variable webform field

Tags: webforms

In my webform I have 3 elements that can be filled: A, B or C. Only one of them will be filled at a time.
Is it possible to fill the bundle field of an entity with the value from one of these webform fields? (the one that is filled?).

In the Webform Content Creator / Manage Fields I can only associate one bundle field with one webform field.

(The reason I have 3 elements in my webform is that only one of them will be visible at a time depending on a previously selected item)